# Windows apache log reader

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I am looking for a simple log reader, not something like awstats.

Just a program that I can have on my computer, download the log file through ftp, open the program, and eg.

see how many times a specific .zip file has been downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Grep (yes, it's available for [windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download)) would make quick work of that.

Comment: hmm, that download link is broken...

Comment: Fixed. (7 characters)

Answer (score 0):

Found one: http://www.weblogexpert.com/